# Adding zip archives to the Document File Type

Tags: 7, files

I have many PDF documents in my site, assigned to the *Document File Type* by the File Entity Module.

I have added a few fields to the content type, thus allowing nice interface in showing all PDF files on the site, with nice filtering.

Now I want to include Zip archives in this interface. (Zip archives are not by default added to any Document type). I have updated the Document type definition to include the mime type application/zip on this page: /admin/structure/file-types/manage/document/edit

Is there any way I can automatically update the existing zip archive files so they are assigned to the Document File Type? As mentioned, there are quite a lot of them and I'd prefer not to have to upload them all again.

Comment: admin/structure/file-types? Thats not Drupal core, right? You must be using a module for this - would be useful to know what module it is. It's also unclear what you want - is there some sort of admin page with an overview of all files, and you want the zip files to show up there?

Comment: Jeff, you are correct, I didn't realise this isn't part of core (I didn't build the site originally and it's big and complex). The relevant module is File Entity https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity

Comment: With regards to what I want, I want zip archives to be defined as the Documents File Type.